# How get List of clusters

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm writing a script to get information about clusters and their VMs.

First I got information about all system's properties like Name, Hosts, CreationDate, ChildClusters etc. In childClusters I have several clusters. How do I get the list of them and their VM?

Code is here:

```
function Get-VMInfo($SystemName) {
    $HostGroupName = 'All Hosts'
    $VMMServerName = 'localhost'
    $report = @()
    $SCVMs = @()
    if ($HostGroupName) {
        $hg = Get-SCVMHostGroup $HostGroupName
        $report += $hg

        return $report
    } 
}
```

Comment: Which virtualization platform and management, if any, are you using? A lot of the information might be readily available with built-in features.

Answer (score 0):

What version of System Center and Windows Server are you using? You can get a lot of the information you need using the System Center PS Shell, but you can also get it using a combination of the Hyper-V and Failoverclusters modules in normal PowerShell.